# Java.Security.Key.getEncoded() OpenSSL DH Equivalent

Tags: java, c, openssl, diffie-hellman

How can I achieve the same result in C with OpenSSL as the getEncoded() Method produces? 
It is required for a Diffie-Hellman Key Agreement and I have to send my public key to a java server (But I think the getEncoded() Method not only encodes the Public Key but also the parameters which should be also required for my case)

My current status is that I have a OpenSSL DH Object which contains the PublicKey and p&g as BigNums.

Would bey very great if anyone knows how to do that.

Comment: Does encoded means DER encoding?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Were you able to find any solution @doptimusprime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If encoded DH object means DER encoded, then i2d_DHParams can help you. It is given [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/dh.html).